# Azure Service Fabric Cluster Deployment Logs

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azureportal

I have a couple of services deployed to a Service Fabric Cluster and I would like to know if there was a way to view some sort of log that would tell me when those services were last deployed. Not necessarily by who, just a time stamp.

Reason is, if I go to my Azure Portal and inspect the services, all of their health statuses are marked as Healthy, yet I am still receiving a `500 Server Error` when trying to ping some of them.

I'm wondering if anyone else may have deployed some services without mentioning it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking at the audit logs for the service fabric cluster?

Comment: Where are those? I haven't heard of that. I am having the same issue. I have a Reliable Service test app running locally, but when I deploy to an on premise cluster, Service Fabric Explorer says everything is OK, and swagger is running and showing my API, but I get a 500 error calling the API, and no application logs show in OMS. I've dug around in the SF\Log folder, but I don't see anything called an audit log.